# PayPal API V2 Create Invoice Wrong Response/Status Code

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm getting the wrong response/status code when creating an invoice using PayPal API V2. I'm getting status code 200 instead of 201 that produces the following response. According to the docs should be returning a Created status code 201 and a JSON response body that shows invoice details

```
"rel" => "self"
"href" => "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-2LMY-9VSE-KKRR-RGYP"
"method" => "GET"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

200 and 201 are essentially interchangeable. The [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v2/#templates-create-response) states:

> A successful request returns the HTTP 200 OK status code and a JSON
> response body that shows template details if you set
> prefer=return=representation.

The format of that HTTP header string should be `Prefer: return=representation`

The default is `return=minimal`, which will only contain the GET link.

Comment: Perfect Thanks :)